# three dimensional integral in Scilab

Tags: scilab

I want to integrate 3D function along x, y and z. for example

```
f(x,y,z) = (x^2+y^2+z^2).^3/2.*exp(x+y+z)*some extra terms....
where 0<x<inf,   0<y<inf,    0<z<inf.
```

I will be thankful if some one help me here.

Comment: could you please provide additional information? You provide a bit of sample code, but don't explain how it doesn't work for you...

Comment: Thanks for the reply @CindyMeister.

Comment: Although my function is more complex but to make it easily understandable I am assuming the following function
`function y = f(x,y,z)
        y = (x^2+y^2+z^2).^3/2.*exp(x+y+z)
endfunction`
Now I want to integrate it first with respect to x from zero to infinity after that integrate it again with respect to y from zero to infinity and at the end integrating with respect to z from zero to infinity.

Comment: Your function f(x,y,z) goes to infinity for big (x,y,z), right? First of all you could visualize the problem. Therefore you have to reduce the dimension by setting x = 0 or changing to spherical coordinates and neglect one angle dimension.

Comment: For the reduced form f(x,y) = ((x^2+y^2)^(3/2))*exp(x+y) you can look at a plot here: [Wolfram Alpha Plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28%28x^2%2By^2%29^%283%2F2%29%29*exp%28x%2By%29)

Answer (score 0):

Take care that Scilab performs a numerical approximation of the integrals with methods which more or less consist in splitting the domain in small intervals
So it is impossible to integrate up to infinity.

You can try symbolic computation tools like Maple, Mathematica, or Macsyma.

Comment: Thanks sir, for the suggestion. But I have written my whole programming in Scilab and its very difficult to write it again in mathematica. Is it possible to integrate a scilab function in mathematica and then insert it back in scilab ??

Comment: No. My proposal holds  if the analytic expression of the function you want to integrate is simple ans is just a part of your Scilab code.

Comment: If your function converges quicly when x, y or z tends to infinity you can use the int3d scilab function and integrating in the cube [0 xmax] x [0 ymax] x [0 zmax]

Comment: Thanks for the discussion. I have wrote a code for Monte Carlo integration and posting it here for those who need it.
 `N=1e6
function integ_fun = intg3d(f,x0,xf,y0,yf,z0,zf,N)
//Monte Carlo integration 
//f = f(xy,z) is the function we want to integrate
//x0 and xf are the limits of x and similarly the limits of y and z are defined
   vol = (xf-x0)*(yf-y0)*(zf-z0)
        xr = (xf-x0)*rand(1,N)+x0
        yr = (yf-y0)*rand(1,N)+y0
        zr = (zf-z0)*rand(1,N)+z0
        sumf= sum(f(xr,yr,zr))
        integ_fun = vol*sumf/N
endfunction`

Comment: The problem with int3d scilab command is it needs a 4xN inputs and my inputs are 100x100x100 matrices